# Does a Boeing 747-830 exist and if it does, is there any difference to a 747-8 (748)

Tags: terminology, boeing-747

Two years ago I've uploaded a video of the Lufthansas Boeing 747 "D-ABYA" to Youtube. I am currently receiving some angry comments on that video because the title reads "747-830 with new Lufthansa livery performs low pass at Hanover Airport". Many people are angry with the label "747-830", telling me that no such thing exists and that the featured airplane is a 747-8 or a 748.

Back when making the video, if I recall correctly, I looked up the type on Jetphotos. It reads "Boeing 747-830". The same is true on Flightradar24. airframes.org tells me the type is B748 and the model is 747-830. However, I could not find a reference to "747-830" on boeing.com.

What are the differences between type and model? Is a type 747-8 always a 747-830? Or are there other models with a similar name (747-8xx)? Am I correct in saying that the airplane is a 747-830?

Comment: I guess [this is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-IUa4Ke5bM). Don't worry too much about angry, ignorant people on the internet (and in real live), don't waste your energy correcting them.

Comment: @DeltaLima that's the one. Uploaded it a few years ago, but it gained 99.9% of it's views in the last week. Sometimes the YouTube algorithm can be funny.

Well, I was wondering if the title was wrong, hence the post. And I'm afraid if I don't correct them, other people might read those comments and get wrong information :-)

Comment: you could consider explaining the 747-8 / -830 detail in the video description. But those that are fast to comment, are probably slow to read! Grüße aus EDDF

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Until 2016 Boeing included **customer codes** into the aircraft model names. Your example 747-830 decodes as follows:

- **747**: This is the general aircraft series.
- **-8**: The 747-8 variant (in this case, a 747-8I, where I is for Intercontinental, the passenger variant).
- **30**: The customer code for **Lufthansa** or **Condor Flugdienst** (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Boeing_customer_codes#First_sequence) for a list of customer codes).

So this makes it a Boeing 747-8 produced for Lufthansa (Condor does not have one).

The term **B748** is the [ICAO code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_type_designators) for the 747-8.

Comment: Additionally 748 is the IATA code code the 747-8 because IATA is always a letter short.

Comment: @Martijn I'm not so sure: the Wikipedia table lists **74H** and **74N** as the IATA codes for the 747-8I and 747-8F respectively. They don't a give a source though...

Answer (score 11):

Yes, a Boeing 747-830 exists.

There are a variety of codes for airplanes, one of the most common being the [ICAO code](https://www.airlinerspotter.com/iata-icao-boeing-airbus-numbers-codes.htm). It lists the latest model of the 747 as B748.

However, Boing uses an additional, airline-specific code. The number 30 is given to Lufthansa and Condor, so the 747-8 in Lufthansa layout is the 747-830.